# Javascript mixin for objects whose properties are objects ambiguity

Tags: javascript

Here is a user-defined mixin for shallow cloning of objects:

```
    function mixin(receiver, supplier) {
      Object.keys(supplier).forEach(function(key) {
         receiver[key] = supplier[key];
      });

      return receiver;
    }
    var supplier = {
        a:{b:10}
    };
    var receiver = mixin({},supplier);
```

and according to my understanding **assigning one object to other makes them equal since they have reference to same object literal and when one object changes its property it reflects on the other object too** but the below tests puzzled me:

```
    receiver.a === supplier.a //true
    receiver.a = {b:20} //but
    supplier.a //still {b:10} I expected {b:20}
```

What am I doing wrong here??
P.S I know about ES6 Object.assign() but this mixin is created just for my understanding.

Comment: But you have two objects, and you're adding the values from the first to the second in a loop, so changing one won't change the other

Comment: You're not modifying the referente object, you are assigning a New object to property a.

Comment: you have removed the initial reference by assigning `receiver.a = {b:20}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment is different from every other operation. It breaks the references because of how it works.

Basically, you have the object in memory, and every variable contains a pointer to the memory location. Thus when you edit that object, you change every reference of it.

*But* if you assign a variable a new value, it puts a new object in a new position in the memory, and changes the reference pointer to the pointer of the new location.

[image]

Comment: But I only changed property b of the already existing object literal {b:10} pointed by both objects a and b.For me it looks the same as normal object pass by references and I still think a and b still point to the same object literal. :(

Comment: @user5381186 No, you created a new object with `{b: 20}`. If you want to change `b`, then you need to do `receiver.a.b = 20`

Comment: WHoops yeah I got it